# Remote desktop server for AVD?

Tags: android, remote-access, android-virtual-device, remote-desktop, vnc-server

Virtualbox has this handy feature that I can enable a remote desktop server of the virtual machine. Does such a feature exists for AVDs? If you would enable the remote desktop server for the AVD, you could connect to it as if it were a remote desktop, and see and control the emulated screen from remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qemu` has built-in support for VNC. You can run the `emulator` with the following options `emulator @AVD -qemu -enable-kvm -vnc 0.0.0.0:32`  Then you can connect on `localhost:5932`.

Comment: what if (1) you want to use vnc with emulator on a windows machine?
also, what if (2) you use it to emulate arm?